# How to access .Net CLR blob items

Tags: c#, clr

I'm playing around with Roslyn, and so far I've learned that a C# string literal is placed in the CLR #US (User String) heap using `System.Reflection.Metadata`, specifically using the `GetOrAddUserString()` method. Then at runtime these strings are accessed via the `ldstr` IL instruction.

I can see that `System.Reflection.Metadata` also contains a `GetOrAddConstantBlob()` method that can place data (including UTF16 strings) on a blob heap. That's presumably the #Blob metadata that can be seen with dotPeek, as can be seen in a screenshot in this blog article:
https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2016/11/15/exploring-memory-allocation-and-strings.html

My question is, how can one access this blob data? Is there some IL instruction corresponding to `ldstr` that does it? Some method in `System.Reflection.Metadata`? Is there any documentation about this? (I have tried Googling all sorts of keywords, but without any luck.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no IL instruction that accesses data from the `#Blob` stream. Instead, blobs are referenced by fields in the metadata tables. For example, the `Signature` column of the `MemberRef` metadata table is offset of the member signature in the `#Blob` stream.

The file format (including the #Blob stream, IL instructions and metadata tables) is defined by ECMA-335 (partitions II and III in particular).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it maybe possible to access items on this #Blob stream via reflection? What I am looking for is some sneaky, or non-standard, way for my modified Roslyn compiler provide data that can be accessed by the generated programs.

Comment: The closest I have seen to direct / arbitrary access to the #Blob stream, is Module.ResolveSignature(int), but I doubt that would help with what you are describing. You could access the blob with native code/pinvoke, but if you are going to do that then its probably easier to just use a Win32 resource. If you need something portable, then an embedded resource is probably a better choice (which you can read using Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(string)).